# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found - Lenovo Yoga 6, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 6 but I can't connect to wifi, it just says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

I can use USB tethering if there's a solution that requires that

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0700000-c07fffff
```

Comment: Did you try and search for a solution? A quick search of this site for Realtek wifi adapter gives me all kinds of same and similar questions with lots of answers.

Comment: @David I did search and tried some solutions - maybe I used the wrong search terms?

Comment: I gave you the term I used Realtek wifi adapter It may also be that a newer kernel already has the driver you need. What kernel are you running?

Comment: uname -r : Find Linux kernel version.

Comment: `uname -r`: `5.11.0-37-generic`

Comment: What is the Ubuntu HWE kernel?
The Ubuntu LTS enablement (also called HWE or Hardware Enablement) stacks provide newer kernel and X support for existing Ubuntu LTS releases. These enablement stacks can be installed manually but are also available when installing with Ubuntu LTS point release media. Maybe change to that kernel.

Comment: I installed `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` as one of my attempts to solve this

Comment: Where in your question does it say this? Nice to hear it is solved but in future questions you need to include ALL info. I would not have wasted my time asking you about something you had already done.

Comment: @David sorry, I tried a lot of different things and don't remember what they were off the top of my head

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the **Realtek PCI adapter** working with Ubuntu, follow these steps:

1. Update the software cache (repository list) and install the required dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
   ```
2. Download and install the correct drivers:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git -b v5
   cd rtw89 && make && sudo make install
   ```
3. Reboot to confirm the installation:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
4. Load the module:

   ```
   sudo modprobe rtw89pci
   ```

Sometimes the installation is not successful. In that case, refer to this:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89#installation-instruction

If there were errors while loading the module, most probably it is due to corrupted/unsuccessful installation. Try reinstalling the drivers and rebooting.

You need to reinstall these drivers every time your kernel gets an upgrade.

1. Change the current directory to the directory we cloned earlier:

   ```
   cd rtw89
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   make clean && git pull
   ```
3. Install the drivers:

   ```
   make && sudo make install
   ```
4. Reload the drivers

   ```
   sudo modprobe rtw89pci
   ```